# How to write conditions in python without repeating words

Tags: python, variables, conditional-statements, repeat

As above. For example,

```
if avariable == 5 or avariable == 6 or avariable == 7:
    print 'hit'
```

What i want to know if there's anyway i can write the conditions without repeating the variable name over and over again, such as:

```
if variable == 5 or 6 or 7:
     print ' hit'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
if avariable in (5,6,7):
      print 'hit'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if avariable in {5, 6, 7}:
    print 'hit'
```